# Redirect URI being overwritten, attempt to use external domain and path for callback C#

Tags: c#, oauth, salesforce, .net-7.0

I am attempting to build a simple API in C# .net7 that will handle the Oauth2 protocol. I followed a YouTube video ([www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUXpfr1LzPE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PUXpfr1LzPE)) for all of my build. I am encountering an issue in which regardless of what I put into my `AuthenticationProperties.RedirectUri`, it will be overwritten with my launched domain, and the `OauthOptions.CallbackPath` appended. What makes it more difficult is the Redirect URI I am trying to use is an entirely separate domain from my launched domain, token endpoint, authorization endpoint, etc. which is managed by salesforce or my localhost. All of the domains are in HTTPS, I had to remove that so my question wouldn't be marked as spam.

I attempted to set some `Oauthevents` in the commented section but that failed.

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("cookie").AddCookie("cookie").AddOAuth("Project", o =>
{
    o.AuthorizationEndpoint = "mysalesforceSite.com/services/oauth2/authorize";

    //o.CallbackPath = new PathString("Something.azurewebsites.net/external/callback");
    o.CallbackPath = new PathString("/external/callback");
    o.TokenEndpoint = "mysalesforceSite.my.site.com/services/oauth2/token";
    o.ClientId = "123456";
    o.ClientSecret = "A123456";
    o.ReturnUrlParameter = "code";
    o.SaveTokens = true;
    o.UserInformationEndpoint = "mysalesforceSite.com/services/oauth2/userinfo";

    //o.Events =
    //new OAuthEvents
    //{
    //    OnTicketReceived = async ctx =>
    //    {
    //        ctx.Properties.RedirectUri = "Something.azurewebsites.net/external/callback";
    //        //builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Project:CustomRedirectUri");
    //        await Task.Yield();
    //    },        
    //     OnCreatingTicket = async ctx =>
    //    {
    //        ctx.Properties.RedirectUri = "Something.azurewebsites.net/external/callback";
    //            //builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Project:CustomRedirectUri");
    //        await Task.Yield();
    //    }
    //};

}).AddCookie().AddIdentityCookies();
```

You'll see below in the `AuthenticationProperties` object instance I am attempting to set the `RedirectUri` to an external site. However it will be overwritten  with my launch domain (local host) and the callback path specified in my `OauthOptions` above.

```
app.MapGet("/Login", () => {

    AuthenticationProperties ap = new AuthenticationProperties()
    {
        RedirectUri = "Something.azurewebsites.net/external/callback",
        //RedirectUri = "Something.azurewebsites.net/external/callback",
        IsPersistent = true,
        AllowRefresh = true,
    };
    
    Debug.WriteLine(ap.ToString());
    return Results.Challenge(ap, authenticationSchemes: new List<string>() { "Project" });
    
});
```

When it completes it will look like this in the URL and swagger - the API UI tool I am using - will state there is a CORS or network issue, but it is really just the redirect Uri not being constructed correctly as it will work in postman when I manually construct it.

What I get at execution:
mysalesforceSite.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=123456&scope=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5005%2Fexternal%2Fcallback&state=CfDJ8P0Iuw_zGJdMlFeGMgyHhYRL4

What I need:
mysalesforceSite.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=123456&scope=&response_type=code&redirect_uri=Https%3A%2F%2FSomething.azurewebsites.net%2Fexternal%2Fcallback&state=CfDJ8P0Iuw_zGJdMlFeGMgyHhYRL4

Comment: redirect uri is picked up from the location the app is running at. yours is running localhost its going to say localhost.  setting it in your code has no effect on what redirect uri is built automatically by the library you are using.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo In the OAuthHandler of the middleware, there is a HandleChallengeAsync function in which it checks if the redirectUri is present or not. If it isn't present it make a default Uri but I am passing a valid string at least so I am unsure why it would be overwritten. But that is far I understand the middleware, it could be overwritten somewhere else to your point.

Answer (score 0):

I think you used

```
app.MapGet("/", (HttpContext ctx) =>
{
    ctx.User.Claims.Select(x => new { x.Type, x.Value }).ToList();
});
```

in your program.cs file and should change MapGet("/" ... to MapGet("/GitAuth" then change the callback in your Github to "http://localhost:5000/GitAuth" you can use your custom keyword for "/GitAuth" and your project localhost port. In this way you have both, homepage and Github authentication.

Comment: I did attempt the name and port change but with no success. I am not using Github, I am using a salesforce based endpoint and that is an externally fixed point I can't change.